# Обновление данных во вкладке

Tags: php, javascript, yii, yii2

Здравствуйте. Пишу портал на Yii 2.0. Подключил гугл мапс. Вывожу все во вьюшку. При этом использую вкладки бутстрапа. Так вот в чем проблема, первая вкладка выводится нормально и данные загружены, а вкладка 3 (та что с картой) подгружает только самый блок гугл мапс (серый). Если карту сделать в первую вкладку то все норм.

Comment: Подождем телепатов

Answer (score 1):

Фреймворк не причем. Все отлично работает. Вот пример на bootstrap tabs:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Map 1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Map 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2818.0283604045553!2d7.669722316214226!3d45.064935768015374!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47886d148758bd89%3A0x961d0199f0fca9b9!2sStamperia!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1461302891281"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3039.2663326103966!2d49.832097416141096!3d40.38078946574716!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40307d90ac16005d%3A0x567b7aafe6b4e062!2sMax+Print!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1461302926529"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: У вас внутри вкладок фреймы, а у меня подтягиваются координаторы с базы даных

Comment: Тогда будьте добры - поделитесь кодом пожалуйста. В качестве данных из бд пусть будут статичные данные

Comment: может засунуть это в Pjax

Comment: тоже вариант...

Comment: но если запихнуть, так это совсем разные блоки

Comment: Доктор, когда я делаю вот так у меня болит. — А вы так не делайте

Answer (score 0):

```
Контролер


<?php
namespace frontend\widgets;

use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
use dosamigos\google\maps\Map;
use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Marker;
use yii\bootstrap\Widget;


class MapWidget extends Widget {
    public $location;
    public $name;
    public $params = array();
    public function run(){
        $coords = str_replace(['(',')'],'',$this->location);
        $coords = explode(',',$coords);
        //print_r($coords); die;

        $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => $coords[0], 'lng' => $coords[1]]);
        $map = new Map([
            'center' => $coord,
            'zoom' => 15,
        ]);

        $marker = new Marker([
            'position' => $coord,
            'title' => $this->name,
        ]);

        $map->addOverlay($marker);
        return $this->render('Maps', ['map' => $map]);
    }
}
```

Вьюха виджета

```
<?=$map->display()?>
```

Вызов виджета

```
<div>
        <!-- Навигация -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#review" aria-controls="review" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Обзор</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photo" aria-controls="photo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Фото</a></li>
            <li><a href="#maps" aria-controls="maps" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Карта</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews" aria-controls="reviews" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Отзывы</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Содержимое вкладок -->
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="review"><?=$result['description']?></div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="photo">

            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="maps">
                <?php echo \frontend\widgets\MapWidget::widget(array('location'=>$result['location'], 'name'=>$result['name'])); ?>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="reviews">
                <?php echo \frontend\widgets\CommentWidget::widget(array('from'=>$result['id'])); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: В базе location хранятся значение (50.456962,30.365421) широта и долгота

Comment: не знаю в чем может быть проблема

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой.

***Быстрое решение проблемы:*** изначально, до загрузки страницы, в коде сделайте вкладку №3 активной:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Google Map</a></li>
```

Далее, при загрузке странице, измените "активность" вкладок Бутстрапа с помощью JQuery, что-то вроде того:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#blockTabs a:first').tab('show');
});
```

В итоге, получится, что при загрузке страницы вкладка с Google Map будет активной и сооответственно загрузится. А вот после выполнения всех скриптов вкладки "встанут" в нужном порядке